# Startup Disk Creator tool for Debian

Tags: usb, installation, debian, debian-squeeze

I was trying to create a USB bootable in Debian to install my new system. I couldn't find any easy to use tool in Debian. I tried downloading the hybrid ISO image from the Debian site and copied it to the USB using the [dd command as said in Debian site](http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb), but it didn't boot.

Next, I used the Startup Disk Creator tool in Ubuntu and it worked like a charm. Is there any similar tool in Debian? I know that there is Unetbootin, but it's difficult to install.

Answer (score 8):

For Debian Stretch (9.x) you can use `gnome-multi-writer`. The interface is a bit confusing (you need to click the [x] button on the left to select ISO) but in the end it does the trick.

[image]

Comment: There's a folder option now. Writing is very slow.

Answer (score 4):

[Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) is a debian package, also available on many other distributions and systems. 
It does install an ISO image as a bootable USB drive.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/unetbootin

Comment: You need to add the repository *sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa* to be able to install this. It would be nice to find a way where the command is included in apt-cache by default.

Comment: I get `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found` in Debian 8.1 when trying to update the package.

Comment: @Masi you should be able to install it in squeeze and wheezy, as listed here: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=unetbootin . Looks like it's not available in Jessie.

Comment: Any similar application available for Jessie?

Answer (score 4):

### Solution with `cp`

I have used the copy (`cp`) command for this.  It did take me a couple of tries, though. The trick that *seemed* to make the difference for me was to plug the usb drive in, format it as MBR, but not create any partitions. In Debian (Gnome), this is easy to do from `gnome-disks` (called simply *Disks* in the GUI, while the package name is *gnome-disk-utility*). It can also be done using the `gparted` GUI program. Of course, you will lose any data currently on the USB drive when you format it.

Then, if your USB drive is /dev/sdd, just issue the copy command in the terminal:

`sudo cp debian-xxx-yyy.iso /dev/sdd`

So you're copying to a drive (that is unmounted), not to a particular partition. Then in the *Disks* GUI, when you click on the newly created partition on the USB drive, you should see *(Bootable)* next to the entry for *Partition Type*. If not, it may help to do the following:

1. With the partition selected, click on the *Gears* icon
2. Click *Edit Partition...*
3. Check the *Bootable* box.

### Alternate solution

Another way that has worked for me with bootable Ubuntu iso images is to use the *Disks* GUI itself:

1. In the top 'three bars' menu, choose *Restore Disk Image...*
2. Under Image to Restore, choose your *.iso* file with a double-click
3. Make sure the Destination reflects your USB drive
4. Click *Start Restoring*. Upon completion, make sure the new partition is bootable as above.

### Notes

1. The OP's link from the Debian site specifically advises against using `unetbootin` for this purpose.
2. The `cp` method is officially sanctioned in the [Debian docs](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/ch04s03.en.html). They add the command `sync` after to ensure writing has finished.

Comment: link to Debian docs on how to write an ISO image: https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb

Comment: There is no MBR option under Format Partition

Comment: MBR is a drive format type, not a partition format type

Answer (score 1):

You can try [MultiSystem](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/) or [LiveUSB](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/liveusb-install-live-usb-creator/).

[Pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) is a very useful resource for this sort of thing.

Comment: Is any of these packages in apt-cache? I could not find them.

Comment: @Masi in what distribution? They're not on Debian or Ubuntu, no, multisystem has its own repository: http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/install

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am using Debian 8.1, Jessie.

Comment: @Masi OK then neither of those are in the repos but you can add the repository from the link I gave in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Win32DiskImager, or rufus.

You may find either of these are the below links, respectively:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/

http://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: These are Windows programs, no?

Answer (score 0):

Also, now there is Balena Etcher:
https://www.balena.io/etcher/